# Effect of HttpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I don't get a good understanding about `HttpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode`, what is the effect of this mode?

I have following sample code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = getHttpURLConnection(_url);
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096); //4k
conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];//10k
FileInputStream in= new FileInputStream(file); //Write the content of the file to the server
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

out.flush();
in.close();
```

Say, The file size is 101k, and I set the chunk size to be 4096.

1. The HttpUrlConnection will send 4096 bytes to the server every write? and 1k for the last time?
2. Note that I have used a 10k buffer to write to the outputstream, Does it matter that the chunk size and buffer size are not the same?
3. If I disable the ChunkedStreamMode in my code, what's the effect compared to the code that I have set 4096?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. The HttpUrlConnection will send 4096 bytes to the server every write? and 1k for the last time?

Yes.

> 2. Note that I have used a 10k buffer to write to the outputstream, Does it matter that the chunk size and buffer size are not the same?

No.

> 3. If I disable the ChunkedStreamMode in my code, what's the effect compared to the code that I have set 4096?

The effect is that the entire output is buffered until you close, so that the Content-length header can be set and sent first, which adds a lot of latency and memory. Not recommended in the case of large files.

Comment: Thanks @ejp for helpful answer. For the 2nd question, I don't understand now.If 4k is written each time, then if the buffer is 10k, then `out.write(buffer, 0, len);` will write 3 times, 4k,4k,2k? Looks it would be better that the buffer size is N*chunksize,like 8k,16k.

Comment: @Tom When you set a chunk size, an internal buffer of that size is created, and written to each time, and flushed when it fills. So you're right about the first two 4k chunks, but the last 2k part of the original write is buffered, and flushed when the next write adds another 2k, and so forth. You really don't need to worry about this.